# Line completion disregarding line prefix

Tags: autocompletion

In Vim, `C-x C-l` performs line completion. However, it expects the prefix of the currently typed line to match the prefix of another line. For example, consider that `|` below denotes the cursor position:

```
; A sentence I would like to auto complete.
...
A sentence|
```

When I press `C-x C-l`, line completion obviously fails because the current line does not start with a semicolon. Is there a way of performing "line" completion that disregards line prefixes?

Comment: To what extent would you define a prefix? Are you looking to just find the first instance of your previously typed string and then fill in til `<eol>`?

Comment: I also thought to ask this question!

Comment: @jecxjo I would define a prefix as everything that appears on the current line from the beginning to the cursor position. What I would like is to search for the prefix of the current line in the whole buffer (even inside other lines) and complete the part of the matched line til `<eol>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's ... built-in. It's just not line completion, because, you're saying it, it's not an entire line you want to complete.

If we start from your example:

```
; A sentence I would like to auto complete.
...
A sentence|
```

If I now press `C-n`, followed by `C-x C-n` (secret sauce! - *context* completion) it will complete the following word. Press `C-x C-n` repeatedly to further complete the next words. If it doesn't work, try it from a `vim -N -u NONE` and go from there.

You should probably use a more complex example, one that have multiple variants, e.g.:

```
; A sentence I would like to auto complete.
; A sentence you don't like to complete.
...
A sentence|
```

In this case, when you hit a "branch" with options (e.g. `I` or `you`), you should select the continuation you want using the usual `C-p` / `C-n` keys, then go on with `C-x C-n` as before.

You can find the docs at `:h i_CTRL-X_CTRL-N`, in the 2nd part (quoted, for reference):

```
    CTRL-N          Search forward for next matching keyword.  This
                    keyword replaces the previous matching keyword.

    CTRL-P          Search backwards for next matching keyword.  This
                    keyword replaces the previous matching keyword.

    CTRL-X CTRL-N or
    CTRL-X CTRL-P   Further use of CTRL-X CTRL-N or CTRL-X CTRL-P will
                    copy the words following the previous expansion in
                    other contexts unless a double CTRL-X is used.
```

Comment: Nice. I knew that it was possible to complete multiple lines by using `C-x C-l` repeatedly, but I had no idea the same works for `C-x C-n`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a single line solution.

```
:inoremap <C-X><C-L> <ESC>mm:/<C-R>=substitute(getline('.'), '\n\+$', '', '')<CR><CR>ggn"*y$'mo<ESC>"*p<ESC>k"_d:nohl<CR>A
```

Mapping to Insert Mode <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>

- `<Esc>mm` Exit insert mode and mark location
- `:/<C-R>=substitute(getline('.'), '\n\+$', '', '')<CR><CR>` Search for contents of this line, removing any new lines at the end
- `ggn` Go to top of file and search for first match.
- `"*y$" Yank from cursor (first match location) to end of line
- `'m` Go back to original edit line
- `o<esc>"*p` Past yank to next line, goofy because we didn't yank a full line, but from cursor to end
- `k"_d` Move back up to original line and delete it
- `:nohl<CR>` if you have search highlighting it is cleared
- `A` append to end of line to continue writing.